# Trying to get numbers from InputBox, split them then add each number into the array

Tags: arrays, vbscript

I have InputBox asking user to input 5 numbers then trying to add each number to the array size 5. But I am getting error. The loop is adding numbers to the array Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You are aware that split makes the array.

Message is your array not arraynums.

Your `for` loop is 0 to 5 which is 6.

Answer (score 0):

Read documentation, e.g. [Split Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0764e5w5(v=vs.84).aspx)

```
Dim i
Dim arrayNums
Dim message
Dim userInput

message = InputBox("Please Enter 5 numbers!")
arrayNums = Split( message)

For i=0 To ubound(arrayNums)  
 msgbox(arrayNums(i))
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. You can just `Split` the results and that will create an array. Then, you can test the `UBound()` of the array to see if you have your 5 numbers.

Here's a loop that continues until 5 numbers are entered:

```
Do
    a = Split(InputBox("Please enter 5 numbers, separated by spaces:"))
Loop Until UBound(a) = 4

' Now, a(0) through a(4) are your 5 numbers.
```

Of course, you'll probably also want to validate the 5 entries to ensure they're actually numbers. The `IsNumeric()` function can help.